# How to send HTTP-request to django inside a docker-compose network?

Tags: django, docker-compose

## Background

I have a project with a frontend- and a backend-service and am trying to access the django server via HTTP-request.

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
services:  
  backend:  
    build: .  
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  
    ports:  
      - "9005:8000"  
    networks:  
      - test-network  

  frontend:  
    image: my-latest-image  
    depends_on:  
      - backend  
    ports:  
      - "9001:80"  
    networks:  
      - test-network  
        
networks:  
  test-network:
```

## Issue

I am able to successfully execute `ping backend` from inside the frontend-container, but if I execute `curl backend:8000` I get the following message from django:
`django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'backend:8000'. You may need to add 'backend' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`

## What I tried

Other people who got this message pointed out to include something like `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['backend']` in their 'settings.py'-file (as the error message pointed out). I already did that and am still getting the exact same error message.

Is there something I still need to configure or should configure differently to communicate with the 'backend'-service from inside the 'frontend'-service?

Comment: did you build your docker image again before running it?

Comment: Yes, I did that. Even tried it multiple times out of desperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The docker documentation and my colleague have lead me to not directly expose my backend's port to localhost. Instead I used a reverse-proxy to forward communication in my docker network. This seems to be better practice and also solved the problem I had accessing my backend-service, which was related to accessing it via localhost.

## My Working Example

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
services:
  proxy: 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: production_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    networks:
      configuration-tool-network:
        aliases:
          - proxy-name

  backend:
    image: my-backend-image
    command: python ./rest_api/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - "8000"
    networks:
      configuration-tool-network:
        aliases:
          - backend-name

  frontend:
    image: my-frontend-image
    expose:
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      configuration-tool-network:
        aliases:
          - frontend-name
      
networks:
  configuration-tool-network:
```

nginx.conf:

```
events {}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://frontend;
    }

    location /api {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }
    
    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8000;
    }

  }
}
```